# Augmenting/Mutating of Model objects in R

Tags: r, time-series, regression, modelsummary

So I am running multiple cochrane orcutt regressions, which is no problem. I then display the output of these regressions using modelsummary(). Still no problems up to this point.

However, when I then try to compare the models using modelplot(), there are no confidence intervals computed in the cochrane orcutt model (class "orcutt") and I thus get the following error:

> Error in eval(parse(text = text, keep.source = FALSE), envir) :
> object 'conf.low' not found

I know what the problem here is - there are just no confidence interval "parts" computed by the cochrane.orcutt() command. A partial solution is also obvious - I can just calculate the confidence intervals using the point estimates/coefficients and the standard errors (which are of course included in the model by default).

However my problem arises when I want to use these confidence interval values in modelplot(), because they are not "in" the model object. In my ignorance, I attempted the following to try and create the lower bound of a confidence interval, using mutate():

```
model %>% 
+   mutate(`conf.low`=`coefficients`-1.96*`std.error`)
```

I hope this conveys my problem well enough, thank you for reading.

Comment: `mutate` is specifically for data frames and tibbles.  You can assign elements of a list (or objects that are based on lists) with `model %>% within(conf.low <- coefficients - 1.96*std.error)`.  I'm not sure if this hack will work with your summary and plot functions though...I'm not familiar with them.

Comment: this sounds like either `tidy` or `confint` would do the job for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, `mutate` is a function from the `dplyr` package which is intended to work on data frames, and *not* on model objects or on `modelsummary` tables.

Also, please note that I can’t diagnose your problem properly because you did not supply a [MINIMAL REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/342331) and you don’t event tell us which function you used to estimate the model.

One way to do the Cochrane-Orcutt in `R` is to use the `orcutt` package:

```r
library(orcutt)
data(icecream, package = "orcutt")
lm <- lm(cons ~ price + income + temp, data = icecream)
coch <- cochrane.orcutt(lm)
```

Behind the scenes, the `modelsummary` package uses the `tidy` function from the `broom` package to extract estimates from model objects:

```r
library(broom)

tidy(coch)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic    p.value
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)  0.157    0.290        0.543 0.592     
#> 2 price       -0.892    0.811       -1.10  0.282     
#> 3 income       0.00320  0.00155      2.07  0.0488    
#> 4 temp         0.00356  0.000555     6.42  0.00000102
```

From the output above, you see that `broom` does NOT extract a confidence interval. This could explain why `modelsummary` can’t print your table/plot.

One alternative option is to instruct `modelsummary` to use the `parameters` package to extract estimates instead of `broom`. This can be achieved by setting a global option:

```r
library(modelsummary)
options(modelsummary_get = "parameters")
modelsummary(coch, statistic = "conf.int", output = "markdown")
```

|  | Model 1 |
| --- | --- |
| (Intercept) | 0.157 |
|  | [-0.439, 0.754] |
| price | -0.892 |
|  | [-2.562, 0.778] |
| income | 0.003 |
|  | [0.000, 0.006] |
| temp | 0.004 |
|  | [0.002, 0.005] |
| Num.Obs. | 30 |
| R2 | 0.649 |
| R2 Adj. | 0.607 |
| rho | 0.401 |
| number.interaction | 11.000 |
| dw.original | 1.021 |
| p.value.original | 0.000 |
| dw.transformed | 1.549 |
| p.value.transformed | 0.051 |

And `modelplot` now works too:

```r
modelplot(coch)
```

[image]

Yet another alternative would be to use the `broom` default, but to customize the output using your own `tidy_custom.orcutt` method. This is a bit more involved, but you’ll find detailed instruction on the `modelsummary` website: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/modelsummary.html#adding-new-information-to-existing-models